Issue with JavaScript window.open() and window.close() functions
I'm trying to use JavaScript to open and close a new window in my web application. The opening part works fine, but I'm having trouble closing the window using window.close().
Here's my code:


let myWindow;
//select dom element
const width = document.getElementById('width');
const height = document.getElementById('height');

//show window object properties 
width.innerHTML = "Window inner with is: " + window.innerWidth;
height.innerHTML = "Window inner height is: " + window.innerHeight;

function openWindow() {
  myWindow = window.open('https://www.google.com')
}

function closeWindow() {
  myWindow.close();
}
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWindow()" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="close window" onclick="closeWindow()" />
</div>




Here is a refactored method to accomplish the desired functionality albeit in a 'pop up' window:
let myWindow;

        const width = document.getElementById('width');
        const height = document.getElementById('height');

        if (width && height) {
            width.innerHTML = "Window inner width is: " + window.innerWidth;
            height.innerHTML = "Window inner height is: " + window.innerHeight;
        }

        function openWindow() {
            myWindow = window.open('http://example.com', '', 'width=800,height=600');
        }

        function closeWindow() {
            if (myWindow && !myWindow.closed) {
                myWindow.close();
            }
        }


Yes its working on a new window not a new tab. thank you

.innerHTML has security and performance implications. Since the text you are setting does not have any HTML .innerHTML should be replaced with .textContent.

Judging by the code, I'd imagine this person is just beginning to learn about web development. Hence why I gave the most simple answer that accomplishes what they requested.

@PritamGhosh if my solution aided in your learning, please mark my reply as an Answer

Thank you both for your insights and suggestions! I'm indeed new to web development, and your explanations help me understand the implications of using .innerHTML versus .textContent. Scott, I appreciate you pointing out the security and performance concerns associated with .innerHTML, and I'll be sure to use .textContent when appropriate.

This is caused by a specific security HTTP header named as Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy.
Websites can specify this header to disallow actions to be performed by the opener (in this case your page), especially when it is cross-domain.
For Google specifically, they have specified same-origin-allow-popups; report-to="gws" in this header so you cannot perform any action since it is not in the same browsing context group.
For websites without this HTTP header, the default is allow. You can try using https://example.com for example and it should work.

Hi @Yogi, that's a good observation. Opening doesn't send any requests to the server yet so there's no way to tell what's the security policy for the particular website. If you call the API to close the window very quickly immediately after opening (eg. setTimeout(() => window.close(), 10)), it will still close successfully. The restriction only applies when the window successfully loaded a document/webpage that has this HTTP header set, which includes navigation.
